# Hashmap only returning last key, value

Tags: android

I am using an `ArrayList` with a `HashMap` inside to parse `JSON` and inflate a dynamic UI. The problem is only the last`key` and `value` are being inserted. I can't figure out why.

This is how I insert the values in `doInBackground()`

```
for (JSONObject s : clientList) {
    Log.v("CHECKING S", s.toString());
    // Iterator containing all the keys
    Iterator<String> iterator = s.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        key = (String) iterator.next();
        value = s.getString(key);
        print("CHECKING VALUES 0: " + key);
        print("CHECKING VALUES 1: " + value);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(key, value);            
        mList.add(map);
    }
}
```

When I'm checking the values they are all there, but when I go to inflate in `onPostExecute()` like this only one is there.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
    // dismiss the dialog
    pDialog.dismiss();
    LinearLayout welcome = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cLLayout3);
    welcome.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
        // get HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = mList.get(i);
        Log.v("RESPONSE", "Creating Client Assessment");
        // find
        LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.c_add);
        // create
        TextView tv = new TextView(Client.this);
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(Client.this);
        LinearLayout client1 = new LinearLayout(Client.this);
        // set
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
        tv1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
        client1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        tv.setText(map.get(key));
        Log.v("KEY", key);
        tv1.setText(map.get(value));
        Log.v("VALUE", value);
        client1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        // add
        client1.addView(tv);
        client1.addView(tv1);
        content.addView(client1);
    }
}
```

My layout inflates with only two `TextViews` and my logcat shows the following

```
06-28 12:05:06.024: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.024: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.024: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.024: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.034: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.034: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.034: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.034: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.034: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.034: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.034: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.034: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.034: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.044: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.054: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.064: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.074: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.084: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.084: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.084: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.084: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.084: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.084: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.084: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.084: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
06-28 12:05:06.084: V/RESPONSE(15300): Creating Client Assessment
06-28 12:05:06.084: V/KEY(15300): Tech Name
06-28 12:05:06.084: V/VALUE(15300):  Jon Doe
```

So whats going on? Where is my `HashMap` being overwritten?

**EDIT**

I see the answers about changing the code to this

```
map.put(key, value);
```

If I change the code to the above then it logcat outcome is virtually the same. Therefor you may be right, but the outcome is still the same, the hashmap is being overwritten. I think the actual error here is on these lines

```
key = (String) iterator.next();
value = s.getString(key);
```

if you notice `key` and `value` are `Strings` that are declared at the very top of the class. I think those are actually the values that are being overwritten inside the `HashMap`. Therefor when I go to pull them out like this

```
tv.setText(map.get(key));
Log.v("KEY", key);
tv1.setText(map.get(value));
Log.v("VALUE", value);
```

They are always the same. Am I right? If so, how would I fix that? Simply declare new `Strings` each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the key and value are two different fields that need to be stored in the map, then I think what you mean to do is something like this:

```
    map.put("key", key);
    map.put("value", value);
```

In addition to that, though, you need to create a new map each time you add it to the array, otherwise you're just going to be adding the same map over and over agin, and each time you call `map.put`, you'll potentially be overriding the values in the previous maps that you've already added to the array.

```
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("key", key);
    map.put("value", value);
    mList.add(map);
```

Then when you're writing them out again, you would read them from the map like this:

```
    tv.setText(map.get("key"));
    tv1.setText(map.get("value"));
```

Comment: @i_me_mine I've updated the answer to match what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: hooray for collaboration! We got it. Thank you very much. Now would you like a bonus question of why my layout is still only inflating two textviews or shall I make another question?

Comment: @i_me_mine Best to ask a new question.

Comment: btw thats a joke, Im gonna try and figure it out on my own, thanks again!

Comment: @i_me_mine Sorry - I'm obviously a bit humour impaired. :)

Comment: no worries my friend humor is not easily detected through text. I got it. It was the old "horizontal when it should of been vertical" in my layout. Have a nice day =)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change

```
 map.put(key, value);
 map.put(value, value);
```

with

```
 map.put(key, value);
```

HashMap holds pair of key and value. If you insert multiple item with the same key, you will find only the last

Comment: see edit, I understand what you mean, but it is not true in this case

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't

```
    map.put(key, key);
    map.put(value, value);
```

be

```
    map.put(key, value);
```

And then use something like  :  `map.getKeys();`
to go over all the keys and get the values?